# Networkx uses graphviz_layout for layout drawing, edge disappeared

Tags: networkx, graphviz

When I use python networkx graphviz_layout to draw hierarchical layouts, the corresponding edge disappears in the generated graph when I try to change the weight of the edge.

Below is the specific code and the image:、

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    edges_weight = np.array([
        [1, 2, 30], [2, 3, 22], [3, 4, 5.97],
        [4, 5, 5.97], [3, 6, 16.03], [6, 7, 4.03],
        [7, 8, 4.03], [5, 8, 5.97], [8, 9, 9],
        [9, 16, 10], [2, 10, 8], [10, 11, 8],
        [11, 12, 2], [12, 13, 2], [11, 13,  10], [13, 15, 8],
        [15, 16, 20], [6, 17, 12], [17, 18, 12],
        [18, 15, 12], [16, 14, 30]])

    G = nx.DiGraph()

    for u, v, w in edges_weight:
        G.add_edge(u, v, weight=w)
    edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
    print(edge_labels)
    shell_pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')

    print(nx.edges(G))
    print(shell_pos.items())
    print(shell_pos.values())

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 15))
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, shell_pos, node_color='lightblue', node_size=1200)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, shell_pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, shell_pos, node_size=1200, arrowstyle='->', arrowsize=10, width=2)
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, shell_pos, edge_labels=edge_labels)
    plt.show()
```

[right draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we0Ca.jpg)

The data is now [11, 13, 10] , and the image is displayed normally at this time

If I change part of the data → [11, 13, 9], the corresponding frame disappears. I don’t know what has happened. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

[wrong draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej0Ek.jpg)

I have searched for various information but have not yet found any valid results

I expect to be able to display the edges 11->13 normally

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is an issue where the edges are overlapping with each other and going behind the nodes instead. An alternative suggestion is to manually plot the nodes hierarchically using `NetworkX`'s `multipartite_layout()` rather than `graphviz_layout()`. It still has overlapping issues but they are easier to resolve by moving the node orders and subset groupings around.

**For Example:**
[Multipartite Layout Version of the Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpBFA.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    edges_weight = np.array([
        [1, 2, 30], [2, 3, 22], [3, 4, 5.97],
        [4, 5, 5.97], [3, 6, 16.03], [6, 7, 4.03],
        [7, 8, 4.03], [5, 8, 5.97], [8, 9, 9],
        [9, 16, 10], [2, 10, 8], [10, 11, 8],
        [11, 12, 2], [12, 13, 2], [11, 13,  9], [13, 15, 8],
        [15, 16, 20], [6, 17, 12], [17, 18, 12],
        [18, 15, 12], [16, 14, 30]])

    G = nx.DiGraph()

    edges = []
    weights = []
    node_subset = {}
    for u, v, w in edges_weight:
        if u not in node_subset.keys():
            node_subset[u] = 10
        node_subset[v] = node_subset[u] - 1
        edges.append((u, v))
        weights.append(w)

    # Sort the nodes
    subsets = sorted(list(set(node_subset.values())))
    subsets = {s: [] for s in subsets}

    for subset in subsets.keys():
        for n, s in node_subset.items():
            if s == subset:
                subsets[subset].append(n)
        subsets[subset] = sorted(subsets[subset], reverse=True)

    # Add Nodes to the Graph
    for subset, nodes in subsets.items():
        nodes = [17.0 if x == 12.0 else 12.0 if x == 17.0 else x for x in nodes]
        G.add_nodes_from(nodes, subset=subset)

    # Make a dict of the edge labels
    edge_labels = dict(zip(edges, weights))

    # Draw the nodes with the multipartite layout
    pos = nx.multipartite_layout(G, align='horizontal')
    nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=1000, font_size=8)

    # Draw the edges 
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=edges, arrows=True, node_size=1000)

    # Draw the edge labels 
    counter = 0
    for edge, weight in edge_labels.items():
        nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels={edge: float(weight)}, font_size=5)

    # Show the plot
    plt.show()
```